# Div text not floating as I want it to when the page shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have designed a page that look how I want it to when the page is wide, but as it narrows it goes wrong.

I have a big pic (grey) to the left with 3 small pics (yellow) to the left of that.

Underneath is a block of text.  When I shrink the page, the small pics drop down below the big pic.  That's good.
But I want the text to flow next to the 3 small pics.  Instead it jumps up next to the big pic and flows round it, then round the 3 small pics.
If I squeeze the screen until its the width of the big grey pic, the text goes how I want it to.

I've read lots of posts but can't see one that helps. I'd be really grateful for some help with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/dovesandchicks/LL93ggxa/

```
#content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
overflow: auto;
}
.SmallPic {
float: none;
width: 150px;
height: 117px;
margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
background-color: #FFFF00;
}
.SmallPicBlock {
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 390px;
}
.BigPic {
float: left;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
width: 520px;
height: 371px;
}
.TextBlock {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: small;
min-width: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
.TextBlock {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks a million, I was tearing my hair out and you have solved this in one line. Brilliant!